# How to use AsyncStorage in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, web-development-server

I want to use AsyncStorage in ReactJs(similar in react-native). I temporarily need to store data in localsotrage (more than 10mb). If there is any other solution please let me know. currently i'm using localstorage of reactjs but as per my research it is limited to 10mb in desktop browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for IndexedDB which is compatible with all modern browsers. The minimum or soft limit is 5MB- the browser will ask for permission to store the data. Maximum storage is the limit of your hard drive disk, as all of the data is stored locally on your machine disk.

You could check [IndexedDB docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API)

You could check the compatibility across the browser [here](https://caniuse.com/indexeddb)